# Touch versus scroll in UIWebView embedded in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have a UIWebView embedded in a UITableViewCell.

The webview content is of a static size and has `.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO`.

The javascript in the webview responds to `touchend` events.

Everything works well except that the `touchend` events fire when the user is scrolling in the table view.

I've tried setting `canCancelContentTouches` on the table view without success.

Is there a way to either stop the javascript event firing when scrolling, or to detect this inside the javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to set a flag in the javascript to indicate that the `touchend` event should be ignored. The `touchend` handler then bails if the flag is set.

The flag is set in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` and cleared in `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`

Setting and clearing the flag is as simple as `[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"ignoreTouchEvents = false;"]`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use UIScrollViewDelegate, it has the following methods:

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
– scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:
– scrollViewDidScrollToTop:
– scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:
– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

Set the "scrollView.delegate" property of your UITableViewController delegate to "self" and do the following, after adding UIScrollViewDelegate to your table view controller (you may not even need to do this, I can't remember but it may be automatically already done and you just have to expose these methods).

```
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:

-> take your webview and "yourWebview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO"

– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:

-> take your webview and "yourWebview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES"
```

This is just one approach. Another might be to make use of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and try playing around with "– gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:"

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work.  The webview gets the `touchstart` event prior to `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` and even if we then disable user interaction the webview will get the `touchend` anyway.